# DateTime.Now represented as GMT Time on a PST Server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I am storing information in a database and setting my POCO's property to DateTime.Now.

When this value is displayed it is appearing as the PST time. I would like it to to display as GMT time.

Do I do something like this to display/store it or is there a better way?

```
TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT");  
var GMTTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime.Now, tz));
```

Also it needs to consider Daylight Savings as UK changes its clocks at different times in the year than USA:

**UPDATE:** I have found that in the TimeZone setting you can pass either GMT Standard Time or Greenwich Mean Time, the first taking into account DST

Comment: The question is ambiguous - what do you mean by "consider Daylight Savings"? Do you want to display the time differently based on whether Daylight Saving Time is in effect in the UK? My answer answers the case where you want it to "consider" Daylight Saving Time in the "detect and discard it" sense.

Comment: I want it to display whatever the time is in the UK. As the USA and UK have different times in the year when their clocks change it just needs to consider this. Either way the end result must be the actual time in the UK

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Store it as [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). It's designed for universal timezone-independent time.

```
DateTime currentUtcTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTime localTime = currentUtcTime.ToLocalTime();
DateTime backToUtcAgain = localTime.ToUniversalTime();
```

Whether a given `DateTime` is already UTC or local time is determined by `DateTime.Kind`. You have to keep this in mind when serializing/deserializing `DateTime` values (e.g from a database) because this information is often not stored and when you get your `DateTime` back, it will most of the time have the value `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`, which may cause issues with conversion methods. I just make sure to force `DateTimeKind.Utc` when I load something in from a persistent data store.

Comment: That doesn't consider Daylight Savings I believe

Comment: @Jon: Yes it does, when converting to local time. UTC itself doesn't have any daylight savings. (Sometimes a local time may be ambiguous admittedly...)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: The OP asks about GMT in context of the timezone of GB, not in context of UTC. GB has daylight savings, so in the summer their timezone will be BST = GMT+1.

Comment: @Daniel: Ah, I'd missed that edit to the question. Sounds like a strange requirement to me. Storing as UTC and then converting it to *any* timezone on request is the most appropriate solution. The OP seems a little confused given the code sample, which appears to be equating GMT and UTC...

Comment: But if I do convert to local time on a PST server wont that be the USA local time not UK

Comment: @Jon it will, if the conversion happens on the server.  But you can still convert to the client specific locale if the client provides you with it.

Comment: @Jon: You should *store* UTC, and then when you want to convert that to a local time, use `TimeZoneInfo` with *whatever* time zone you're interested in. You need to distinguish between "local UK time" and "UTC time" - at the moment you appear to be mixing those up a bit.

Comment: I haven't mentioned UTC! The end result needs to be local UK time whatever time of the year

Comment: @Jon then what do you mean by GMT, its practically UTC

Comment: And as for storing it, UTC is probably more robust, but given a SQL server with a consistent locale (in your case the server will always be en-US), then the locale conversion will be handled for you, so long as you keep it a DateTime in the database.  Try it, save the en-GB 25/12/2011 to the database, the database will save it as 12/25/2011 (hopefully!).

Comment: @V4Vendetta LOL! Its practically the same! Good enough then!

Comment: @I've set the globalization to en-GB in the web.config so I think it will store it as en-GB format

Answer (score 1):

there's `DateTime.UtcNow` if that meets your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at DateTimeOffset.

I'd propose to change your DateTime property to this  type

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx)
[DateTime vs. DateTimeOffSet](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/06/14/datetimeoffset-a-new-datetime-structure-in-net-3-5-justin-van-patten.aspx)

Comment: Agree. Never ever use `DateTime` for global dates again!

Answer (score 0):

You could add it into an extension method to make it nicer

```
public static DateTime ConvertToGreenwichMeanTime(this DateTime utcDateTime)
{
    return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDateTime, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time"));
}
```

Then just call it

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ConvertToGreenwichMeanTime();
```